# ImageMagick: Convert images into multiple images with different width?

Tags: imagemagick

I have a folder with many high-res images (in `jpeg`, `jpg`, `png`). I want to convert every image into images in `jpeg` with the width of `2500`, `1440` and `640`, and place them in a folder called `output`.

I also want to add the width of the image as a suffix to the image filename (i.e. `red-ball.jpg` -> `red-ball-640.jpeg`, `red-ball-1440.jpeg`, `red-ball-2500.jpeg`).

How can I do this with ImageMagick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make output directory
mkdir output

shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.jpg *.jpeg *.png; do
   base=${f%.*}
   ext=${f##*.}
   echo Converting $f to output/$base -2500 -1440 -640 $ext
   convert "$f" -resize 2500 -write "output/${base}-2500.${ext}" \
                -resize 1440 -write "output/${base}-1440.${ext}" \
                -resize 640 "output/${base}-640.${ext}"
done
```

**Sample Output**

```
Converting test.jpg to output/test -2500 -1440 -640 jpg
Converting z.jpg to output/z -2500 -1440 -640 jpg
Converting z2.jpg to output/z2 -2500 -1440 -640 jpg
Converting z3.jpg to output/z3 -2500 -1440 -640 jpg
Converting z4.jpg to output/z4 -2500 -1440 -640 jpg
Converting z1.jpeg to output/z1 -2500 -1440 -640 jpeg
Converting a.png to output/a -2500 -1440 -640 png
Converting black.png to output/black -2500 -1440 -640 png
Converting c.png to output/c -2500 -1440 -640 png
Converting d.png to output/d -2500 -1440 -640 png
Converting f2.png to output/f2 -2500 -1440 -640 png
Converting gantt.1.png to output/gantt.1 -2500 -1440 -640 png
Converting globe.png to output/globe -2500 -1440 -640 png
Converting h.png to output/h -2500 -1440 -640 png
Converting output.png to output/output -2500 -1440 -640 png
Converting result.png to output/result -2500 -1440 -640 png
Converting result2.png to output/result2 -2500 -1440 -640 png
```

The `shopt -s null glob` ensures that if there are no `jpg` files, or `png` files in your directory, that the glob (`*.jpg` or `*.png`) expands to nothing rather than generating an error message. Further info [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob).

The `ext=${f##*.}` finds the shortest thing following a period (full stop), which is basically the file extension. This is called *"bash parameter substitution"* and the best description I know of is [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Comment: Cool! Thanks! Could you explain `shopt -s nullglob` and `ext=${f##*.}`?

Comment: Thank you! Superb answer! :)